# Difference between Compute Node and Compute Cluster

Tags: cluster, supercomputer

I have to give a presentation on Super Computing and I came across this pdf 
http://yuva.cdac.in/YuvaII/YUVA_2%20leaflet.pdf. As mentioned in page 2 what is the difference between Computer Node and Compute Cluster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this context a Cluster is a group of Nodes.

Note that it tells you in your linked leaflet that each Cluster is (upto) 225 Nodes.

(Very) Basically, the Nodes do the computing work, and the Cluster allows them to work together as one.

For general info:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

*In data communication, a physical network node may either be a data communication equipment (DCE) such as a modem, hub, bridge or switch; or a data terminal equipment (DTE) such as a digital telephone handset, a printer or a host computer, for example a router, a workstation or a server.* **[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28networking%29)**

**Node** could be a computer and **Cluster** is a group of Nodes *i.e, a group of computers*.